# How to use PCL python in ROS?

Tags: python, pcl, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to build python-pcl against pcl_ROS?

I am using ROS Kinetic, Ubuntu 16.04, python2.7

## Motivation

I wish to use PCL functionality (PointCloud_PointXYZRGB) in a python ROS node.

## Context

I found that python-pcl 0.2.0 built against PCL 1.7.2 but that the function I needed: pcl.PointCloud_PointXYZRGB() wasn't available, only pcl.PointCloud()
I don't know if this is the limits of PCL 1.7.2 or python-pcl

After a lot of messing around I managed to get python-pcl 0.3rc1 to build against PCL 1.8 (built from source) with cython 0.25.2 and I found that this gave me the functionality that I needed.

*Ideally* I would like to be able to build some version of python-pcl against pcl_ROS, we are probably going to do dozens of ROS/python-pcl installs and I found building and installing PCL 1.8 to be quite error prone and difficult to diagnose - plus we then have multiple versions of PCL on every system and I'm concerned about that causing complications.

Any ideas about the best way to proceed?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/324736/how-to-use-pcl-python-in-ros?/) by [LukeAI](https://answers.ros.org/users/38953/lukeai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 131 on 2019-06-05

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is now easy, python-pcl 0.3 has since been published to pip which works with the default 1.7.2 PCL

---

Originally posted by [LukeAI](https://answers.ros.org/users/38953/lukeai/) with karma: 131 on 2019-11-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Petros ADLATUS](https://answers.ros.org/users/99003/petros-adlatus/) on 2022-04-22**:
any installation commands?

**Comment by [LukeAI](https://answers.ros.org/users/38953/lukeai/) on 2022-04-25**:
pip install python-pcl

**Comment by [Petros ADLATUS](https://answers.ros.org/users/99003/petros-adlatus/) on 2022-05-10**:
Python3: pip install python3-pcl